# tic tac toe in C-error in comparing data

Tags: c, if-statement

When I run my program, the if statements inside the else-if function carries out for any input by user.When I enter 'x' in the slot [0][0] player 1 wins :(, i did even try board[0][0]!=' ' it did not work.In the if function I compared the boards diagonal inputs and the boards horizontal and vertical inputs but i'm not sure what the mistake is.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char xo = 0,board[3][3]={
        {' ',' ',' '},
        {' ',' ',' '},
        {' ',' ',' '},
    };
    int row,col,i,win=0,player=0;

    for(i=0; i<9;i++)
    {   
        printf("   1   2   3\n");
        printf("1| %c | %c | %c |\n",board[0][0],board[0][1],board[0][2]);
        printf("2| %c | %c | %c |\n",board[1][0],board[1][1],board[1][2]);
        printf("3| %c | %c | %c |\n",board[2][0],board[2][1],board[2][2]);

        player = player%2+1;

        jump:
        printf("Enter 'x' , 'o' or 'q'(to quit): ");
        scanf(" %c", &xo);

        if( xo == 'q' || xo == 'Q')
        {
            printf("Thank you for playing!!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else if( xo =='X' || xo =='x'||xo == 'o'||xo == 'O')
        {
            printf("Enter row: ");
            scanf("%i",&row);
            printf("Enter column: ");
            scanf("%i",&col);

            board[row-1][col-1] = xo;
            /*these functions and statements dont work according to my inputs*/
            if((board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[2][2])
            ||(board[0][2]==board[1][1]&&board[1][1]==board[2][0]))
            {
                printf("Player %i wins\n\n",player);
                printf("   1   2   3\n");
                printf("1| %c | %c | %c |\n",board[0][0],board[0][1],board[0][2]);
                printf("2| %c | %c | %c |\n",board[1][0],board[1][1],board[1][2]);
                printf("3| %c | %c | %c |\n",board[2][0],board[2][1],board[2][2]);
            }
            else
            {
                for(i=0;i<3;i++)
                {
                    if((board[0][i]==board[1][i] && board[1][i]==board[2][i])||
                        (board[i][0]==board[i][1] && board[i][1]==board[i][2]))
                    {
                        printf("Player %i wins\n\n",player);
                        printf("   1   2   3\n");
                        printf("1| %c | %c | %c |\n",board[0][0],board[0][1],board[0][2]);
                        printf("2| %c | %c | %c |\n",board[1][0],board[1][1],board[1][2]);
                        printf("3| %c | %c | %c |\n",board[2][0],board[2][1],board[2][2]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input!!! Please re-enter,\n");
            goto jump;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: change to like this `xo == board[0][0] && board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[2][2]`  (`scanf(" %c", &xo);xo=toupper(xo);`)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: STRONGLY STRONGLY STRONGLY recommend re-designing the code to not use a `goto` statement.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  It contains the unused variable `win`.

Comment: the declaration for `board[][]`  can be much easier written as: `#define MAX_ROWS (3)   #define MAX_COLS (3) .... char board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS] = { ' ' };

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using an `enum` or `#define` statements to give the 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code.  The 'magic' numbers are 3, 3, 9,

Comment: since `0` is not equal to `o` and `X` is not equal to `x`,  strongly suggest, after this line: `scanf(" %c", &xo);` you insert the line: `xo = tolower( xo )'.    note: `tolower()` is defined in the header file: `ctype.h`

Comment: the code has logic errors: 1) this line: `player = player%2+1;` will not work correctly because `+` has a higher precedence than `%`   suggest: `player = (player%2)+1;`  which will yield values of 1 and 2.  2) the comparisons for checking if a player has won need an additional check that (for instance) the first entry in the winning set is not ' ' so a winner will not be declared when nothing has been entered.

Comment: strongly suggest handling the validating of the user input (and any resulting error message) be in a tight loop centered around the call to `scanf()`.   Then no `goto` statement needed.  Suggest using a `switch()` statement immediately after the call to `scanf()` with cases for `o`, `x`, `q`  and a `default` that handles invalid input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
||(board[0][2]==board[1][1]&&board[1][1]==board[2][0]))
```

This line is true even if no one entered a cross or a circle inside these cells, because

```
' ' == ' ' == ' '
```

Instead try initializing the cells with `a` to `i` characters, as in

```
char board[3][3] = {
    {'a', 'b', 'c'},
    {'d', 'e', 'f'},
    {'g', 'h', 'i'}
};
```

So that when the if-statement runs,

```
'c' != 'e' != 'g'
```

Comment: this is my assignment and i have to use the blanks (' '), i tried to add <pre><code>||(board[0][2]==board[1][1]&&board[1][1]==board[2][0]&& board!=' ')) it still doesnt work

Comment: @M.Ashfaaq I know I didn't notice you used chars. Edited.

Comment: thank you for the response, i did use the numbers and alphabets(numbers worked for char :| ) and my program works but is it possible to use the blanks?

Comment: Ehr, again, no, sorry .-.

Comment: Accept answer? No? :(

Comment: Note that the strictest (compiler-like) parsing of `' ' == ' ' == ' '` evaluates to false (because `' ' == ' '` evaluates to `1`, and `1 == ' '` evaluates to false in all code sets I'm aware of).  However, your meaning is clear enough; I'm picking nits for the sake of doing so.

Comment: An alternative to using the initialization is to check that one of the cells is not blank: `(board[0][2] != ' ' && board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0])`.

Comment: thanks for the answers guys, but i did try out Jonathan's method(one cell not blank)and it did not work :(.

Comment: The complete code for that if statement (Jonathan method) should be `((board[0][2] != ' ' && board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0]) || (board[2][0] != ' ' && board[2][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[0][2]))` if I guess right (with a ' ' initialized board)